# Java - Save newly drawn canvas to bitmap and display back in imageView

Tags: java, android

I have this code where I am receiving RectF coordinates based on detecting an object from where the user has uploaded an image.

```
img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, 128, 128, true);
                    try {

                        Android model = Android.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

                        // Creates inputs for reference.
                        TensorImage image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(img);

                        // Runs model inference and gets result.
                        Android.Outputs outputs = model.process(image);
                        Android.DetectionResult detectionResult = outputs.getDetectionResultList().get(0);

                        // Gets result from DetectionResult.
                        float score = detectionResult.getScoreAsFloat();
                        RectF location = detectionResult.getLocationAsRectF();
                        String category = detectionResult.getCategoryAsString();

                        // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                        model.close();
                        // here we will print out the results of the object to text views based on the image that is inputted by the user
                        // we print out object type and its accuracy score
                        objecttv.setText(category);
                        scoretv.setText(Float.toString(score));
                        textBox.setText(newText);


                        boxPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        boxPaint.setAlpha(200);
                        boxPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                       // here I am trying to create a new canvas to draw on with the location provided by the model and then save that back to a bitmap to display back with the newly drawn rectangle.

                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img);
                        canvas.drawRect(location,boxPaint);

                       
                        imageBox.setImageBitmap(img);
                    }
```

This is clearly wrong as I am receiving a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Paint.setColor(int)' on a null object reference`

What way can I modify it to draw the newly created rectangle on the original image and display it back into my imageView?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I done to get this working.

```
try {

                        Android model = Android.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

                        // Creates inputs for reference.
                        TensorImage image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(img);

                        // Runs model inference and gets result.
                        Android.Outputs outputs = model.process(image);
                        Android.DetectionResult detectionResult = outputs.getDetectionResultList().get(0);

                        // Gets result from DetectionResult.
                        float score = detectionResult.getScoreAsFloat();
                        RectF location = detectionResult.getLocationAsRectF();
                        String category = detectionResult.getCategoryAsString();
                        //Create a new canvas to draw on
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img);
                        //draw on the canvas with the given location from the model
                        drawBoundingBox(canvas, location);
                        // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                        model.close();
                        // here we will print out the results of the object to text views based on the image that is inputted by the user
                        // we print out object type, accuracy score and location of object on the image

                        objecttv.setText(category);
                        scoretv.setText(Float.toString(score));
                        textBox.setText(newText);
                        imageBox.setImageBitmap(img);

                    }
```

```
void drawBoundingBox(Canvas canvas, RectF location) {
        // Draw what you want
        Paint boxPaint = new Paint();
        boxPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        boxPaint.setAlpha(200);
        boxPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(location, boxPaint);
    }
```